# Images in Django email template not loading in email

Tags: django, django-templates

I'm using a template to send an email using Django. The email gets sent but the images are not displayed.

In the template html file, I have:

```
{% load static %}

<img class="margin-bottom" height="52px" width="140px" src="{% static 'images/image.png' %}" />
```

In the settings.py file, I have the following:

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static")]

STATIC_URL = env('STATIC_URL', cast=str, default='/static/')

STATIC_ROOT = env(
    'STATIC_ROOT', cast=str, default=os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "collected_static")
)
```

And I have my images in a folder called images in the static folder.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to use MultiPart and cid:. It is almost always a bad idea to send html mails with images. It gives spam points to your mail and smtp server

Try This

```
from email.mime.image import MIMEImage
from django.core.mail import EmailMultiAlternatives

subject = 'Django sending email'
body_html = '''
<html>
    <body>
        <img src="cid:logo.png" />
        <img src="https://www.google.com/logos/doodles/2015/googles-new-logo-5078286822539264.3-hp2x.gif" />
    </body>
</html>
'''

from_email = 'hello@localhost.com'
to_email = 'hi@localhost.com'

msg = EmailMultiAlternatives(
    subject,
    body_html,
    from_email=from_email,
    to=[to_email]
)

msg.mixed_subtype = 'related'
msg.attach_alternative(body_html, "text/html")
img_dir = 'static'
image = 'logo.png
file_path = os.path.join(img_dir, image)
with open(file_path, 'r') as f:
    img = MIMEImage(f.read())
    img.add_header('Content-ID', '<{name}>'.format(name=image))
    img.add_header('Content-Disposition', 'inline', filename=image)
msg.attach(img)
```

Comment: Thank you. That worked. I'm also having a similar problem with a custom font I want to apply to the email: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67332023/applying-custom-font-to-a-django-email-template

Answer (score 0):

What happen is gmail has it maximum email size or let me say if the image you are trying to load is very high it wont show it my show in ios mail app but it wont show in some others so you have to make the image size low but i would advice you to use https://imgur.com/  in which you upload your image and then you can just load it in the html . Example you can check this and it would work i currently used 540px image for it also .

```
<img style="width: 150px;object-fit: contain;color: #ff3838;border: 0;-ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic;"
                     alt="Gimsap"
                     src="https://i.imgur.com/xVWEwWg.png">
```