# Applying custom font to a Django email template

Tags: css, django, django-templates

I'm styling a Django email template using inlinecss, but my custom font is not being applied to the email.

In the css file (included using `{% load inlinecss %} {% inlinecss "css/styles.css" %}` in the html file), I have the following:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'my-font';
    src: url("../fonts/my-font.woff2") format("woff2"),
        url("../fonts/my-font.woff") format("woff");
}
```

Any idea how I can get my custom font to get applied to the email?

Thanks.

Comment: usually emails don't support custom fonts.

Comment: `url("../fonts/my-font.woff2")` your urls are a relative path, this when the user reads the email would not resolve to your server but to the users email providers domain.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat even using an absolute path doesn't work.